# Get full video picture from FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm getting the picture field (poster image) from a [video node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/) through the Facebook Graph API.

It works, but the response contains the picture in 128x128 pixels format.

Does anyone have any idea how to get a bigger (the full) one?

Comment: Your **tools/explorer** link doesn't do anything. Just says _"application limit reached"_. Show a link to an actual `.png` or `.jpg` then maybe the large size URL can be figured out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed the field 'format' from the video node. This field contains an array with the thumbnails as well in multiple formats.